# req.body do node.js vazio no rest da angular+

Tags: node.js, angular, rest

Boa tarde

Estou criando uma API em node.js e estou com problemas no req.body recebido pelo express. O problema se resume a não conseguir pegar as variáveis rest post enviada pelo angualr9, quando eu crio um formulário e direciono para a rota do arquivo node.js ele acha as variáveis porem no rest do angular as variáveis vem no arquivo (consigo vela no debug do navegador) mas não chega ao servidor. Desde ja agradeço a atenção dos colegas.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');

const config = require('../../config/config');
const port = config.server.port;

const servPontoDeVenda = require('../../api/pages/loja/pdv');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

app.get('/get', (req, res) => {
    res.json(servPontoDeVenda.get(req));
});

app.post('/post', function (req, res) {
    console.log('bod', req.body); //esta vindo vazio
    res.json(servPontoDeVenda.post(req));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: não tem nenhum erro no código nodejs, executei aqui, e enviando corretamente: 
`$ curl -d '{"teste": 42}' -H 'content-type: application/json' http://localhost:3000/post `
os dados chegam:
`bod { teste: 42 }`

o seu erro está na camada frontend.

Comment: Testei o código tb, quando envio json está ok, o problema é quando envio formdata. Provavelmente este é o método de envio via formulário html.

Comment: Poderia me mandar o formato que vcs estão enviando no front-end? O engraçado é que eu ja utilizo este método no front-end para uma api em PHP.

Comment: faz o contrario, diz como você tá enviando.. qual o tipo? tá indo form data?

Comment: Cara achei o erro para a api php eu tenho um método tratado para receber e enviar os dados todos passa por este método e ele utiliza JSON.stringify(objJSON) e isto estava danificando ou algo do tipo no node.js. Muito obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 0):

Como está realizando sua requisição? Tente adicionar esses cabeçalhos.

```
fetch(`${url}/teste`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({"a": "teste"})
})
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que o problema esteja em quem está dando o cast para json no objeto enviado.

Você alterando de:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

para

```
app.use(express.json());
```

deve funcionar.